# Please help in improving this query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query on a 16+ Million row table is very slow. Running for more than 30 mins.

I created a non-clustered index for the columns.

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, COUNT(ColE)
FROM   TABLE
WHERE (ColF > N'00007000000') AND ColD IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE
```

Is there a way to improve the query performance please?

Comment: We will at least **need** your query plan, and the DDL of your Table, *including* any relevant indexes on it.

Comment: What data type is `colf`?

Comment: I don't think it's using your non clustered index because ColF probably isn't an nvarchar, so it may be casting every value in ColF to nvarchar before doing the comparison. But without a query plan and what datatypes you're using, this is impossible to say.

Comment: Is there an error in your query? You have ColE in the GROUP BY clause but after select you're instead counting it.

Comment: What is the index you created (Column order is important)? Is the filter on ColF always fixed on the value in the example or will it change? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` for the table including all indexes? What does the execution plan look like? How many rows match the `WHERE` clause? How many groups do you expect? What version of SQL Server? If Azure what performance tier?

Comment: Can you add Actual Axecution Plan ?

Comment: Hello All, Thank you for your comments. Is there a way to put the execution plan without mentioning the production tables and column names?
I created this index and removed the Unicode. The query takes 45 mins to return 8million rows.
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Performance_Index] ON [dbo].TABLE
(
    [ColD] ASC,
    [ColF] ASC
)
INCLUDE([COLA],[COLB],[ColC],[ColE])

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove UNICODE sign:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, COUNT(ColE)
FROM   TABLE
WHERE (ColF > '00007000000') AND ColD IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE
```

because `NVarchar` is 16 bit and Unicode comparison rules are a lot more complicated than ASCII - special chars for the various languages that are supported at the same time require quote some more processing

Comment: You *assume* that the `ColF` isn't an `nvarchar`. We really don't have the information to guess that.

Comment: @Larnu you are right. So is it better to delete reply?

Comment: Up to you. The OP hasn't responded to anyone's requests for DDL, or query plans, so the question is impossible to answer. I would say this guess is better than telling the OP to use `NOLOCK` though. 

Answer (score 0):

You can use with(nolock) keyword without blocking and please check your index ColF column. Because nvarchar types columns sorting so slow rather than integer Types.

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, COUNT(ColE)
FROM   TABLE **with(nolock)**
WHERE (ColF > N'00007000000') AND ColD IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE
```

PS: with(nolock) is dangerous keyword because when use this keyword getting non-completed transaction data..

Comment: The OP *appears* to have an `nvarchar` type column, not a `varchar`. Also, if you are using `NOLOCK`, you should let the OP know about all the caveats that come with it, and the inaccurate data it can return.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you have provided, only we can offer limited solutions about this query performance.
 The proper index for this query will be like the following because this index will cover the all required columns and where conditions

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Performance_Index] ON [dbo].TABLE
(
    [ColD] ASC,
    [ColF] ASC
)
INCLUDE([COLA],[COLB],[ColC],[ColE])
```

- **COLD** and **COLF** should be placed in the index key columns
- **COLA**, **COLB**, **COLC**, and **COLE** should be in the included columns index key columns.

  However, if the execution plan does not use this index you are facing an **implicit conversion** problem. This issue due to the performance problems in the queries. The query could not use the proper index because there is a mismatched data type in the query. You can identify this problem with help of the following query ;

  `SELECT  DB_NAME(t.[dbid]) AS [Database Name], 
  t.text AS [Query Text]
  FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs WITH (NOLOCK)
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS t 
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS qp 
  WHERE CAST(query_plan AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE ('%CONVERT_IMPLICIT%')
   AND t.[dbid] = DB_ID()
  ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Other than these options;

- Index fragmentation
- Update statistics